Could not locate statistics in the system catalogs error in SQL Server
I've been trying to access a table on our reporting server (secondary replica) from our warehouse server via a linked server. Everything was working smoothly until last week, but now it's throwing a "could not locate statistics in the system catalogs" error.
After some research, it seems that I may need to drop and re-create a statistic that's causing this hiccup. However, I'm hesitant to do so on our live production server. I'm still a bit unclear about what's causing this problem exactly.
Could someone kindly explain what might be going on and if there's a workaround that wouldn't involve dropping and re-creating stats? I truly appreciate your assistance and time. Thank you!

This is documented here

Seems like you are bumping into a bug that sometimes happens in AGs, the process which updates the statistics on the secondary can get blocked/hampered from running.
Try running this first on the secondary replica:
DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE('ALL')
GO

This should force SQL to refresh statistics (and other system caches) on the secondary and is a healthy option. It could be that there is an issue with that particular statistic and scripting it as a drop and recreate on the primary could also work, but try the above fix first. I wouldn't expect this to happen all the time, I've seen it a time or two among our clients and it seems to be a "lottery" sort of thing where if the right ingredients are present you can bump into it.
You can see a lot more details here also.

Dropping the cache is not an option for me. Can I just drop the statistic itself? I experimented with using OPENQUERY instead of linked_server.table_name and managed to access the table. While it may not be applicable in every situation, it's worth a try. Although it's not a permanent fix, it could offer temporary relief.

Why is it not an option for you? it's a safe thing to do. I don't believe the Linked Server is your issue here - you can figure that out easily enough by just running the query on the secondary directly and see if you get the same experience.
You can certainly drop and create the stat - but it has to be on the primary replica. since the secondary is read only and dropping/adding a stat is write.

Ok, I'll try out this option to see if it works. It's just that I have to convince a lot of people before this can be done. That is why I was looking for alternatives. Thank you so much for your time and help! Really appreciate it!

@lifeisajourney FWIW, you should be updating statistics regularly anyway. If you're not, you guys are most likely doing something wrong. It's important for helping generate accurate execution plans for your queries. Not sure why anyone at your company would need convincing otherwise.
